# How to I loop through AWS CLI output?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to pass a list of values from a aws cli query to another command.
Even though I have seen plenty of examples in AWS, when I try all the values come together:

```sh
  policy_versions=`aws iam list-policy-versions --query "Versions[].VersionId" --policy-arn $POLICY_ARN --output text`
  echo "policy_versions=$policy_versions"
  for ver in $policy_versions; do
    echo "first version: $ver"
  done
```

Which then prints out:

```
policy_versions=v3  v2  v1
first version: v3   v2  v1
```

My value of `ver` is the entire string, it should be `v3` then `v2` and `v1`. But It is instead:
`v3    v2  v1`.

I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your results and I traced the results to a difference between shell and `zsh` (which is now used as the default shell in MacOS).

Put simply, you can run this command to make it work the way you expect: `setopt shwordsplit`

For more details, see: [iteration - Shell script - iterate over space separated words/characters (in zsh) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46056564/shell-script-iterate-over-space-separated-words-characters-in-zsh)

Comment: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!THANKYOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Seriously this thing lost me like hours haha Thought I was going crazy much appreciated.